# Constants not available for jest tests in Actions

Tags: javascript, facebook, reactjs, jestjs

When I run navAction-test.js below I get following error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'DATA_LOADED' of undefined

As I understand it the constant.DATA_LOADED is undefined, I'm guessing jest is mocking it and for this reason constant is undefined, I've tried everything I could find on the next but it remains undefined.

Is there anyone out there who can help. I would really appreciate it.

navAction.js:

```
var dispatcher = require('../dispatcher/AppDispatcher');
var constants = require('../constants/constants');

module.exports = {

    load: function() {
    def = $.ajax({
        url: 'http://api.facebook.com/',
        data: {},
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            dispatcher.dispatch({type: constants.DATA_LOADED, data: data});
        }
    });
    }
}
```

navAction-test.js:

```
jest.dontMock('../navAction.js');

describe('Tests NavigationCollectionActionCreators', function() {

    var $;
    var dispatcher;
    var navAction;

    beforeEach(function() {
    $ = require('jquery');
    dispatcher = require('../../dispatcher/AppDispatcher');
    navAction  = require('../navAction.js');
    });

    it('tests calls $.ajax & dispatcher ', function () {
    navAction.load();
    $.ajax.mock.calls[0][0].success({body: {header: {items: [{name: 'The name', link: 'http://www.facebook.com'}]}}});

    expect(dispatcher.dispatch).toBeCalledWith({type: 'DATA_LOADED', data: [{name: 'The name', link: 'http://www.timeout.com'}]});
    });

});

//constants.js
var keyMirror = require('keymirror');

module.exports = keyMirror({
    DATA_LOADED: null,
});
```

UPDATE:

I got this to work by adding the following to navAction-test.js:

```
var constants = {
    DATA_LOADED: 'DATA_LOADED',
    DATA_NOT_LOADED: 'DATA_NOT_LOADED'
};
jest.setMock('../../constants/constants', constants);
```

Is this the correct way of doing it?

Comment: I've updated the code block above to add the constants require

Answer (score 1):

Add to test:

```
jest.dontMock('../constants/constants');
```

If you do not want to use automocking at all, you can remove all of the `jest.dontMock` and put instead:

```
jest.autoMockOff();
```

Your method to solve the problem (in the update at the bottom) is not appropriate in my opinion because it violates DRY (do not repeat yourself). What happens when you added another action constant? Now you have to remember to add it in the test too. That is problematic.